# elasticsearch dsl scan results

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

Can someone point me to how to extract the results `_source` from the generator when using the scan API in the elasticsearch dsl python client?

for example, i'm using (from this example, [elasticsearch-dsl scan](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html))

```
for hit in s.scan():
    print(hit)
```

I get the following

```
<Hit(beacon/INDEX/_Mwt9mABoXXeYV0uwSC-): {'client_number': '3570', 'cl...}>
```

How do I extract the dictionary from the hit generator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every `Hit` has `to_dict()`, hence you can just do `hit.to_dict()`:

```
for hit in s.scan():
    print(hit.to_dict())
```

**Note**: `hit.to_dict()` doesn't convert meta info, you can get the meta from the meta object, i.e.:

```
hit_dict = hit.to_dict()
hit_dict['meta'] = hit.meta.to_dict()
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @ami-hollander answer - *.to_dict()* did not convert meta info (id for example), if you need this info you can do something like:

```
hit_dict = hit.to_dict()
hit_dict['meta'] = hit.meta.to_dict()
```

Comment: I have to give it to the meta part. Thanks a lot. FYI: `scan()` gives back `null` scores, you can however extract the score from `explanation` (given you have set the `extra` for `explain`) and use it to sort the results as well. Cheers